Why divide by the same factor in a loop in factorization?
function Factors(remainder) {
    var factors = [], i;

    for (i = 2; i <= remainder; i++) {
        while ((remainder % i) === 0) {
            factors.push(i);
            remainder /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

Can we just use if instead of while?
function Factors(remainder) {
    var factors = [], i;

    for (i = 2; i <= remainder; i++) {
        if(remainder%i===0) {
            factors.push(i);
            remainder /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}


because it will not produce the same result

Try it and see if the result is the same.

the while will keep dividing remainder by i as long as your condition is true. But if you use an if instead, it will check it only once and remainder might still be divisible by i but since your loop doesn't continue then it won't produce the same result

Run this in the debugger with Factors(8). Then try changing while to if and run it in the debugger again. You should see a difference

Try it on a number divisible by a square, specifically.

This snippet demonstrates the difference between using while and using if


function FactorsWhile(remainder) {
    var factors = [], i;

    for (i = 2; i <= remainder; i++) {
        while ((remainder % i) === 0) {
            factors.push(i);
            remainder /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

function FactorsIf(remainder) {
    var factors = [], i;

    for (i = 2; i <= remainder; i++) {
        if ((remainder % i) === 0) {
            factors.push(i);
            remainder /= i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

console.log("Using WHILE: " + JSON.stringify(FactorsWhile(4)));
console.log("Using IF: " + JSON.stringify(FactorsIf(4)));




The if statement will only check if remainder is divisible by i at that moment.
The while loop will keep dividing remainder by i as long as remainder % i === 0 (i.e., remainder is divisible by i). It ensures that all factors of i are captured.

The reason is because the function you with the while is looking for prime factors. Meanwhile, the function with an if only finds a few factors which may or may not be primes. Let's use the number 12. If you run the function with the while, the resulting array should be [2,2,3], meanwhile, using the if statement, you get [2,3]. The first answer is the correct one because 2 x 2 x 3 = 12 and every number in the array is a prime number, meanwhile 2 x 3 = 6.
